# How to use pyarrow.compute.is_in function?

Tags: python, pyarrow, apache-arrow

im trying to find whether an pyarrow array of values is in another pyarrow array of values, similar to pyspark or pandas isin function. According to the docs i should be able to use

```
pyarrow.compute.is_in(values, *, memory_pool=None, options=None, value_set, skip_nulls=False)
```

but cant figure out how to use it properly, i've tried the following:

```
array1 = pa.array([1,2,3,4])
array1 = pa.array([1,4])
```

hoping to get

```
pyarrow.compute.is_in(array1,array2)
#<pyarrow.lib.BooleanArray object at memaddres>
#[
#  true,
#  false,
#  false,
#  true
#]
```

but instead get the folling errors:

1. cp.is_in(array1,array2):
   `ArrowInvalid: Function is_in accepts 1 arguments but attempted to look up kernel(s) with 2`
2. cp.is_in(values = array1,value_set = array2):
   `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'values'`

Im using python 3 with pyarrow -v 5.0.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Found it. In some mail archive just got to pass `value_set` as keyword argument without values.

```py
cp.is_in(array1, value_set=array2)
```

Comment: You will notice that the function signature has a standalone `*` in it. That means that all arguments _after_ `*` must be provided as keyword arguments. As `value_set` comes after the `*` is must be provided as a keyword argument as you noticed.

See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102 for additional info

Comment: wow thanks! im pretty new to python so im just learning about the standars of it all. Much appreciated!